# NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver - Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, lubuntu, cuda

I want to install `Cuda` on my computer. So I did this:

Step 1:

```
hp@hp-hpz400workstation:~$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
[sudo] Mot de passe de hp : 
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:0f:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000DD8sv0000103Csd0000084Abc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF106GL [Quadro 2000]
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

hp@hp-hpz400workstation:~$
```

Step 2:

```
hp@hp-hpz400workstation:~$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-390
```

Step 3:

```
hp@hp-hpz400workstation:~$ nvidia-smi
Tue Dec  1 19:55:52 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.138                Driver Version: 390.138                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro 2000         Off  | 00000000:0F:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 30%   56C   P12    N/A /  N/A |     42MiB /   959MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       591      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            40MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
hp@hp-hpz400workstation:~$
```

Step 4: I donwload the new `Cuda 11.1` software for my `GF106GL [Quadro 2000]` card.

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=2004&target_type=debnetwork

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2004.pinsudo mv cuda-ubuntu2004.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/ /"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

Step 5: When I restart the computer, I had to write this to start the screen.

```
hp@hp-hpz400workstation:~$ startx
```

Step 6: I checked what has gone wrong

```
hp@hp-hpz400workstation:~$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

hp@hp-hpz400workstation:~$
```

Step 7:

[image]

**Questions:**

1. What graphics driver should I have?
2. What Cuda version should I have?

Comment: does this help (https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/sort-of-solved-cuda-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-gf106gl-quadro-2000-10de-084a/82824)

Comment: @wraith3690001 I will try. Give me a moment

Comment: Hm...I think I have too old computer...and graphic card.

Answer (score 0):

Check the requirements for cuda 11.1, Your Quadro 2000 has only a compute capability of 2.1, so is limited to CUDA 8.0.

See [Legacy Quadro products](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-legacy-gpus)

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932864/cuda-compute-capability-requirements for the list of CUDA version vs compute capability